# Intel VTune Cannot Find .so

Tags: c++, boost, intel, intel-vtune

I have an application I'm trying to profile using Intel VTune. I can run the app on the command line with `app -play foo.rec /dir/foo.so` without a problem.

In Intel VTune, I attempt to run a profile using the following parameters:

[image: VTune]

However, when I run this job, I get the following error:

```
IOException : anchor IOException : Cannot load DSO '/dir/bin/foo.so': 
libboost_system-il-mt-d-1_50.so.1.50.0: cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory
```

I have verified that `libboost_system-il-mt-d-1_50.so.1.50.0` is in the same directory as `foo.so`. How can I tell Intel VTune to look for this directory in the same directory as `foo.so`? In general, how can I tell Intel VTune to look for any .so in any directory?

Comment: Your command line example seems to be inconsistent with Application parameters screen-shot. I.e. "foo.rec" vs. "/dir/foo.rec" and "/dir/foo.so" vs. "dir/bin/foo.so". Is this misprint or something else? In general where (from which directory?) do you regularly run your application?   Often this type of error could be "fixed" by changing "Working directory" (see combo-box below "Application parameters") for application which could only be run from specific sub-dir. Another typical root cause of such errors is not invoking VTune GUI from the same shell, where all required env variables are set.

Comment: try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/boost/libs/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`